# Rails search form, two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am trying to implement a search field in Rails 4 to find data behind two models. I have two controllers: buildings and rooms, and two models: building and room. A building, naturally, has many rooms and a room belongs to a building, which I have stated in the respective models.

**Basically, a user could type either a building or a room name into the search form and it would return a response with details about the building or room.** Of course, a building needs to have an address, and a room needs to know in which building it is with the address as well. So I'd need to display different details according to the searched for instance. Both have the same String attribute `name`, so this could make things easier.

I have no luck in finding a relevant example on how to implement such a search form. This is the working basic search I have at the moment in `views\buildings\index.html.erb`, which can only search buildings:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "buildings", action: "show"}, method: "get", class: "nifty_form") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:name, "Search for a building (later also rooms):") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:name) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

This is the `show` method in `controllers\buildings_controller.rb`:

```
def show
  @building = Building.where('lower(name) = ?', params[:name].downcase).first
end
```

And this is the route it refers to:

```
get 'buildings/:id' => 'buildings#show'
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: You should have a in-between step which would list all the results matching the given name, displaying both Building and Room. And then on this page you can display a "show link" of the resource. All of this can be done via AJAX, but it makes it a lot more complex.

Comment: A drop-down menu (google-style) of all the matching names under the search field would be nice indeed. Then, a user could click any of these, and the app would act accordingly (use appropriate controller?). Any more specific ideas on how to implement this? Examples? I am new to Rails, so tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to add the search code in the index method of buildings controller, there are many things you can do but here is what i will recommend:

```
def index
   # 
   if params.has_key?(:name)
     @buildings = Building.joins(:rooms).
                  where([
                     'lower(buildings.name) like ? or lower(rooms.name) like ?', 
                     "%#{params[:name].downcase}%",
                     "%#{params[:name].downcase}%"
                  ])
   else
     # your normal code goes here.
   end
end
```

Any other information you need such address ( is that a different model ) can he included in there.

Hope this helps,

PD: if necessary you can render a different view when a search is present inside your if block

```
render action: 'my_custom_view', status: :ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to time restrictions, I decided to merge these models into one common model, Space. It holds all the information that a building and a room needs. Thanks anyways!